# Remove the [status]

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

In nearly all the [status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status) Questions I've looked at, that tag was added only because there was some concept of the word in the Question content. That means it is not useful, except in the cases where it should be renamed to [http-status-codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-codes).